# Iphone X randomly shuts down and keeps restarting and is hard to turn on afterwarss

Tags: iphone, shutdown, reboot

I have an iphone X for 3 years maybe now (bought it after a few months from release) after a few months from buying it, if i remember correctly in summer, it shut down suddenly and kept restarting with apple logo until battery ran out.

I tried out different combinations afterwards and it sometimes worked at some combinations and sometimes didn't.

For some reason this happens rarely in winter but happens almost 3 times or more a day in summer. Today it flashed a red screen between restarts (by restarts i mean when it shutdown and kept showing apple logo then turn off then show apple logo then turn off for so many times)

The way i fix it is by pressing
Volume Up->Volume Down->Hold power button until it shows apple logo then turn off (turns off because i held down the power button and not because it completed a cycle of turning on and then off). Doing so will make it stop this restarting cycles. Then after doing so i try different combinations, it seems to work on different situations as for example: sometimes it works when holding power button + volume up until 3 seconds after apple logo shows (but this method rarely works)
Or ,which is the better one and has a higher chance of working, by pressing volume up then down then power button until apple logo appears for a few seconds.

What annoys me is that the iphone doesn't get too hot and other phones (even another iphone x that i know a person uses) don't do such things at the same temperature even though they might be on Cellular Data and having a really thick case for their phone.

I thought it was a graphics card issue but if it was so, then why does it occur at summer most of the times.

Also it never shuts down while the phone is unlocked, it only shuts down whenever i turn it off or the screen turns off by itself. And somwtimes in summer i try to put it in the fridge to lower its' temperature but still this thing happens even when the phone is at 4°C (after putting in the fridge for a while so it might be 10°C but the thing is that it is cold and definitely isn't 40°C or more or somewhat less)

Comment: In my opinion you have an issue with the iPhone hardware (EG the system board) The key indicator for me was, it happens more in the summer than the winter, making it heat related and likely due to a heat sensitive, failing IC, somewhere in the phone. Time to take it in for repair.

Comment: So,in your opinion, it is not a software issue, or a gpu related issue (as this is similar to gpu failures in PCs). When i get it to a repair shop, what should i tell him about this?

Comment: it doesn't *matter* if it is a GPU issue. The iPhone uses Apple SOC (System On a Chip) which means the GPU is not a discreet part, it's all in the main CPU chip and the large bulk of the chips on the system board.

Comment: So basically, fixing it would mean changing the SOC and basically the phone itself as it is embeded into the motherboard

Comment: *Most likely.* Understand that we are getting only the info you have supplied us and judging from that it is a **likely** hardware issue, it is, at best, an educated guess. But that guess is based on limited information. Your best bet is to take it to an Apple (or other) store and have it looked at.

Comment: Ok i will do that (once i have enough money)

Comment: But how would i test to see if it was a software issue? I don't think it is so because i downloaded many updates since then and even many major updates so i don't think it is a software issue, but is this enough to check?